# Fetching an object's position in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do I fetch the x and y positions of an object created in tkinter for Python 3? Will try to produce a moving object which will move to another random position after hitting x = width or y = height!

Comment: What do you mean by "object"? Is it a widget, or is it an object on a canvas?   Please read and follow the advice at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If the 'object' is a tkinter widget, you can get it's position by using the `.winfo_x()` and `.winfo_y()` methods.

```
x = widget.winfo_x()
y = widget.winfo_y()
```

If the 'object' is a tkinter canvas item, you can use the canvas `.coords()` method.

```
x = canvas.coords(object)[0]
y = canvas.coords(object)[1]
```